# $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)=e^{-(x+y+z)}$, find P(X<Y<Z) and P(X=Y<Z)

Tags: probability, order-statistics

$\begin{equation}f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}e^{-(x+y+z)} &\mbox{x,y,z>0}\\0 &\mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}\end{equation}$ $Find \ P(X<Y<Z)\ and\ P(X=Y<Z)$

What I have done is $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)=e^{-(x+y+z)}=e^{-x}e^{-y}e^{-z}=f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)f_{Z}(z), x,y,z>0$, so X,Y,Z are independent. 
$P(X<Y<Z)=P(X<Y)P(Y<Z)P(X<Y)$, and$P(X<Y)=\int P(X<Y|Y=y)f_{Y}(y)dy=\int P(X<Y)e^{-y}dy$

I know I did someting wrong, anyone could help me? Thanks!

Comment: Hints: Since $X, Y, Z$ are independent and identically distributed (prove this if it is not immediately obvious!), all $3!=6$ orderings of $(X,Y,Z)$ are equally likely. For the second part, observe that the set $\{X=Y\}$ is a superset of $\{X=Y<Z\}$. What is the probability of the former event? What does that tell you about the probability of the latter event?

Comment: You're correct that they're independent (and from that and the fact that they all have the same distribution, you should be able to write down the probability by simple symmetry). $P(X<Y<Z)\neq$ $P(X<Y)P(Y<Z)P(X<Y)$. Are you sure you wrote the second part of the Q. right?

Comment: I got it, so the answer is $\frac{1}{6}\ and\ 0$, thanks very much